# VBA - Recognize typos in email domain

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a VBA script that is to work through an extensive list of email addresses and flag the ones that are suspected of being wrong.

I'd like to refine the routine by adding a function that would spot typos in common domain names such as gmail, hotmail, msn, skynet, etc. I'll have a list of these common display names in an array.

The string function would see if the inputted string looks similar but is not the same as an element in the array, and return true as boolean if it is the case.

Idea is to spot erroneous entries such as: homtail, mns, slynet, hotmal, yahooo, etc.

Not looking for a script per se, looking for inspiration of how to tackle this problem...

Answer (score 2):

a fuzzy comarison is what you need - there is code [here](http://code.google.com/p/fast-vba-fuzzy-scoring-algorithm/source/browse/trunk/Fuzzy1) that will compare two strings, and give you a score from 0 to 1 depending on how close they are. It will be up to you to decide how close they are to do automatic substitution.

example results:

```
server        text           fuzzy score
-------       --------       -----------
hotmail       hotmale        0.7619048 
hotmail       hot            0.4285714 
hotmail       notmail        0.8571429 
hotmail       NotEvenClose   0.1944444 
hotmail       hotmail        1 
hotmail       yellow         0.0952381 
hotmail       homtail        0.7142857
```

The the source code has been released under GNU Lesser GPL

---

in case of link rot, here's the code:

```
Public Function Fuzzy(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As Single
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, d1 As Integer, d2 As Integer, p As Integer
Dim c As String, a1 As String, a2 As String, f As Single, o As Single, w As Single
'
' ******* INPUT STRINGS CLEANSING *******
'
s1 = UCase(s1)        'input strings are converted to uppercase
d1 = Len(s1)
j = 1
For i = 1 To d1
    c = Mid(s1, i, 1)
    Select Case c
        Case "0" To "9", "A" To "Z"        'filter the allowable characters
            a1 = a1 & c        'a1 is what remains from s1 after filtering
            j = j + 1
    End Select
Next
If j = 1 Then Exit Function        'if s1 is empty after filtering
d1 = j - 1
s2 = UCase(s2)
d2 = Len(s2)
j = 1
For i = 1 To d2
    c = Mid(s2, i, 1)
    Select Case c
        Case "0" To "9", "A" To "Z"
            a2 = a2 & c
            j = j + 1
    End Select
Next
If j = 1 Then Exit Function
d2 = j - 1
k = d1
If d2 < d1 Then        'to prevent doubling the code below s1 must be made the shortest string,
    'so we swap the variables
    k = d2
    d2 = d1
    d1 = k
    s1 = a2
    s2 = a1
    a1 = s1
    a2 = s2
Else
    s1 = a1
    s2 = a2
End If
If k = 1 Then        'degenerate case, where the shortest string is just one character
    If InStr(1, s2, s1, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        Fuzzy = 1 / d2
    Else
        Fuzzy = 0
    End If
Else        '******* MAIN LOGIC HERE *******
    i = 1
    f = 0
    o = 0
    Do        'count the identical characters in s1 and s2 ("frequency analysis")
        p = InStr(1, s2, Mid(s1, i, 1), vbBinaryCompare)
        'search the character at position i from s1 in s2
        If p > 0 Then        'found a matching character, at position p in s2
            f = f + 1        'increment the frequency counter
            s2 = Left(s2, p - 1) & "~" & Mid(s2, p + 1)
            'replace the found character with one outside the allowable list
            '(I used tilde here), to prevent re-finding
            Do        'check the order of characters
                If i >= k Then Exit Do        'no more characters to search
                If Mid(s2, p + 1, 1) = Mid(s1, i + 1, 1) Then
                    'test if the next character is the same in the two strings
                    f = f + 1        'increment the frequency counter
                    o = o + 1        'increment the order counter
                    i = i + 1
                    p = p + 1
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
        If i >= k Then Exit Do
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    If o > 0 Then o = o + 1        'if we got at least one match, adjust the order counter
    'because two characters are required to define "order"
finish:
    w = 2        'Weight of characters order match against characters frequency match;
    'feel free to experiment, to get best matching results with your data.
    'If only frequency is important, you can get rid of the second Do...Loop
    'to significantly accelerate the code.
    'By altering a bit the code above and the equation below you may get rid
    'of the frequency parameter, since the order counter increments only for
    'identical characters which are in the same order.
    'However, I usually keep both parameters, since they offer maximum flexibility
    'with a variety of data, and both should be maintained for this project
    Fuzzy = (w * o + f) / (w + 1) / d2
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called Hamming codes (or hamming distance) - 
 try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)